# Asking for Various proofs of uncountability of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, reference-request

How many different proofs are there of the uncountability of the set $[0,1]$ ? I know of the nested interval proof and the Baire Category theorem proof ; please suggest other proofs . Thanks in advance .

$EDIT$ : Is there a proof of this uncountabilty using Shroder-Bernstein Theorem ?

Comment: The 'Cantor diagonalization proof' is one.

Comment: I don't tink that the Schroder-Bernstein theorem is the right tool for this, because it only says that some sets have bijections between them. It can never be used to prove non-existence of a bijection, although, if you know that no bijection exists, it tells you that injections can only go one way.

Answer (score 5):

Matthew H. Baker of Georgia Institute of Technology uses a [game](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0606253.pdf).

[image]

Comment: in the given link , page 2 , 4th line from top , how is it that $\alpha < b_n , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ ? I only see $\alpha \le b_n , \forall n \in \mathbb N$ ; moreover from it  how does it follow that $\alpha \notin S$ ?

Comment: Nice. Not sure. Maybe it's supposed to be that $a_n < b_n$?

Comment: Oh sorry. I misread. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that $a_n < b_n$? Can Alice's limit be one of Bob's choices?

Comment: Since they both have to choose strictly monotonous sequences, the limit $\alpha$ of Alice's sequence has to be strictly larger than any $a_n$ and strictly smaller than any $b_n$.

Comment: @Arthur Does it? Limits of sequences need not be part of the sequences right?

Comment: Yes, you're right about that, and I still stand by my comment. Since $[a_{i+1},b_{i+1}]\subset(a_i,b_i)$ for all $i$, we must have $\alpha\in (a_i,b_i)$ for all $i$ as well.

Comment: What are some other interesting games you would like to recommend to others? (Not limited to OP's question)

Answer (score 4):

The game proof given by BCLC is nice!

The classical ones that I know are the following:

1. Direct use of the nested interval theorem : given a sequence of real numbers, construct a real number different from all the numbers in the sequence as the common point of a nested sequence of intervals. (This proof is already pointed out in the question).
2. The proof using the decimal expansion of real numbers : given a sequence of real numbers given by their decimal expansion, use the diagonal method to produce a real number whose decimal expansion is different from all the ones you are given. (This one should be that suggested in Prahlad's comment).
3. A variant of 2, where one first shows that there are at least as many real numbers as subsets of the integers (for example, by constructing explicitely a one-to-one map from $\{ 0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$ into $\mathbb R$), and then show that $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ is uncountable by the method you like best.
4. The Baire category proof : $\mathbb R$ is uncountable because 1-point sets are closed sets with empty interior. (Also pointed out in the question).
5. The measure proof : $\mathbb R$ is uncountable because $1$-point sets have measure $0$. (This is in idm's answer).

5'. The measure proof without measure. First show that a countable set $D$ is *negligible* in the following sense: for any $\varepsilon >0$, $D$ can be covered by a sequence of intervals $(I_n)$ such that $\sum_0^\infty \vert I_n\vert<\varepsilon$. Then show that a nontrivial interval $I$ is *not* negligible in this sense, by proving that if $I$ is covered by a sequence of intervals $(I_n)$, then $\sum_0^\infty \vert I_n\vert\geq \vert I\vert$ (this requires some work).

Without any doubt, there are lots of other proofs. For example, an amusing one in this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0901.0446v1.pdf I also found a proof using "only" the completeness property in Theorem 8.1 of this paper: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5119.pdf

Comment: This is the best answer..

Comment: I knew the author was just being humble!

Comment: Btw some of your proofs are kind of repeats of others already presented...?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, I should have said that; and actually I will.

Comment: @BCLC This is done, now.

Comment: "Mathematically this proof is very similar to Cantor’s first proof. Alice chooses the left
endpoint of each interval In and Bob chooses the right endpoint. When Alice wins it means
she has found η which is not in the sequence {ωk}. However this proof is much easier to
visualize than the proof of Theorem 2.1. This gave us the idea to write Cantor’s other
proofs with a game argument. "

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why he downvoted??

Answer (score 2):

There are many I think.

**I can give you this one:**

Let $m$ be Lebesgue measure. If a set is countable, then its measure is null (but the converse is not true e.g. the cantor set). We have that $$m([0,1])=1>0.$$ Therefore, [0,1] is uncountable.

Comment: But how would you prove that a countable set has empty interior, that seems just as difficult as the original question..

Comment: No, I put the proof in my previous post.

Comment: @Matthew All the elements of a countable set are isolated points right?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ has no isolated points...

Comment: @MatthewLevy: Nice :-) I erased it form my proof. Tks,